# How can I create an internal database in a c++ program?

Tags: c++, database

During the run of my c++ program I have an amount of data that I will use.
I want to be able to use some of it depending on some criterion. In other words, a kind of data base with request instructions.

Is it possible to create an internal database and use it with DB request instructions?

I don't need to save the data either before or after the run.

Edit:
It won't be feasable in my case to add other C libraries, I'll have to work with what i'm provided with.

Comment: [`boost::multi_index`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/) is like a DB

Comment: Your requirement is seriously under-specified. How will you access this data? What kind of data? How much? How is it structured? Until you can answer these questions nobody, not even you, will be able to come to a decision on what technology to use.

Comment: like and HDF database with nodes and sub-nodes. The last sub-node (deeper) contains data (Strongs and/or Doubles). The data is in memory (variables)

Comment: Sounds like you need to support querying the database. I hear jQuery is quite popular.

Answer (score 3):

You may like to have a look at [SQLite in-memory database](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html).

Alternatively, use a container with one or more indexes, e.g. `boost::multi_index`.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use some database theory:
1. Store all the records into `std::vector`.
2. Use `std::map` to build search / index tables.

The index tables will give you quicker search times on keys without having to sort all the data.  The index table will be of the form `std::map<Key_Type, unsigned int>`, where the `unsigned int` is the index into the `std::vector` database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a in memory structure, depending on how big this database needs to be. Is it a collection of Structs or is it a proper relational database or just tons of unstructured data?

Comment: It's about a 100 value, they are not  STRUCTs, basically doubles and Strings

Comment: A collection like a DoubleLinkedList or Vectors or something equivalent would be the best. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_stl_tutorial.htm